# Can publish a DotNet console app for armeabi?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, arm, embedded-linux

I'm trying to compile a basic hello world and run it on a ARM32 device running Linux.
The problem is that when I execute the command:
dotnet publish -r linux-arm
it generates an executable that is compiled using the armhf compiler, but my board architecture is armeabi, so I cannot execute the program.

Is there any way to compile DotNet for armeabi architecture?
I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 and I don't find any option besides linux-arm (armhf) and linux-x64 (but my board is 32 bits)

Comment: Are you doing this on Windows?! Then you probably need to ask MS or related guys about this. In Linux it's possible to compile Mono for almost any supported architecture.